# In IE getting error like "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In IE getting error like:

```
 "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"
```

Here is my sample code:

```
 if (!test[0].childNodes || !test[0].childNodes.length || 
                                     !test[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {
        test1 =test[0].childNodes ="";
   }else{
        test1 =test[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   }
```

Could you please help me on this. Please suggest me is there any solution

Comment: Can you tell us the intent of your code, to properly make a suggestion?

Comment: you need specific with your question,this is incomplete code.

Answer (score 1):

[`childNodes` is a read-only property of Nodes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)